# Android SQLiteDiskIOException disk I/O error (code 522)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Yesterday from Crashlytics I noticed `disk I/O error (code 522)` while opening the database. Problem is that this crashed already has been reported from 16 users 36 times. Sadly I can't reproduce this error. Here's the code fragment where error occurs

```
SessionDbManager(Context context, String tripDbFileName) {
        this.context = context;
        this.tripDbFileName = tripDbFileName;
        this.tripDbHelper = new SessionDbHelper(this.context, tripDbFileName);
        SQLiteDatabase database = null;
        int attempt = 1;
        while (database == null) {
            try {
                database = this.tripDbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // here's the error
            } catch (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException e) {
                Crashlytics.logException(e);
                XLog.e("Failed to load history data from database ", e);
                if (attempt == 5) throw e;
            }
            attempt++;
        }
        db = database;
    }
```

And here's the stack trace

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 522): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:932)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:677)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:363)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:337)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:251)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:195)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:808)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:793)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:737)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:289)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
       at eu.fishingapp.data.sql.session.SessionDbManager.(SourceFile:51)
       at eu.fishingapp.data.sql.session.SessionContentProvider.update(SourceFile:753)
       at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.update(ContentProvider.java:384)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:1412)
       at eu.fishingapp.data.sql.session.SessionDbHelper.renameSessionDb(SourceFile:584)
       at eu.fishingapp.data.network.synchronization.FileSyncServiceImpl.uploadFile(SourceFile:462)
       at eu.fishingapp.data.network.synchronization.FileSyncServiceImpl.uploadSessions(SourceFile:221)
       at eu.fishingapp.data.network.synchronization.FileSyncServiceImpl.uploadSessionsFiles(SourceFile:243)
       at eu.fishingapp.data.network.synchronization.FileSyncIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:116)
       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:67)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I have read about I/O error and found two possible answers I was thinking that this is because users ran out of free space on their devices. But here's some images from two app users
[image]

[image]

So this is definitely not storage issue :( Any ideas how to solve this problem?

EDIT: targetSdk version 22

Comment: what is user os version? if api level > 23. its runtime permission exception

Comment: @AmodGokhale thanks for your comment api level is 22

Comment: interesting... is there reason you are opening writable database in loop? If its just for showcasing error.. i'll recommend to open a bug report with google.

Comment: what the value you pass for tripDbFileName ?

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa It's the database name. Guarantee is't not null :)

Comment: @AmodGokhale I've got this exception from user with api 23 but everything work perfect with api >= 23 on my devices without given runtime permissions. May there be other cause?

Comment: Any solution found for this?

Comment: Did you find anything related to this?